# Remove class 'selected' from another function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an ng-class function which add the class 'Selected' through a toggle function. I want to remove ALL the items classes that have this 'Selected' class when this function runs.

### controller.js

```
    $scope.addItemToggle = function(item) {
        item.selected = !item.selected;
        if (item.selected) {
            $scope.items.push({
                itemName: item.itemName,
                itemIcon: item.itemIcon,
            });
        } else {
            var index = $scope.items.indexOf(item);
            $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
        }
    };
```

### view.html

```
 <ul class="outfit-icons row">
     <li class="outfit-button col-33" ng-repeat="item in clothing" ng-class="{'selected':item.selected}" ng-click="addItemToggle(item)">
        <div class="item-tick">
            <i class="ion-android-done"></i>
        </div>
      </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an index parameter to your function :

```
 <ul class="outfit-icons row">
     <li class="outfit-button col-33" ng-repeat="item in clothing" ng-class="{'selected':item.selected}" ng-click="addItemToggle(item, $index)">
        <div class="item-tick">
            <i class="ion-android-done"></i>
        </div>
      </li>
  </ul>

$scope.addItemToggle = function(item, index) {
    $scope.items.forEach(function (item, i) {
        if (i !== index) {
            item.selected = false;
        }
    });
    if (item.selected) {
        $scope.items.push({
            itemName: item.itemName,
            itemIcon: item.itemIcon,
        });
    } else {
        var index = $scope.items.indexOf(item);
        $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
    }
};
```

Comment: kind of. I want the items that current have a 'selected' ng-class to revert back to its normal state and not have the selected class on the div.

Comment: I need to call this from another scope function. How can I do this?

Comment: It's not the cleanest way, but you can save something like ```$scope.selectedIndex = index;``` in ```addItemToggle```, and then use ```$scope.selectedIndex``` in your other function.

Comment: It still didn't work. When I come back to the state, the items are still showing the selected class. Is there a way to refresh it back to its original state before I checked them?

Comment: Can you do a jsfiddle or plunkr so I can help you better ?